# How can I estimate the required number of iterations of Gauss-Legendre algorithm?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, programming

I have the following datastructure in Haskell for computable numbers $\mathbb{M}$:

```
data Computable = Exact Rational | Inexact (Word -> Integer)
```

`Exact` labels numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$. `Inexact` labels Cauchy sequences whose limit is in $\mathbb{M}$, like this (using lambda calculus):

$$
\text{Inexact}^{-1}(x) = \lambda k. \lfloor x × 10^k \rceil
$$

Note that numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be labeled `Inexact`. In other words, numbers labeled `Exact` has guarantee to be in $\mathbb{Q}$, while those labeled `Inexact` doesn't.

I want to declare `instance Floating Computable`, which requires a definition of $\pi$. I decided to implement it using Gauss-Legendre algorithm, like this:

```
approximateQ :: Rational -> Word -> Integer
approximateQ q n = round (q * 10 ^ n)

inexactToReal :: (Word -> Computable) -> Computable
inexactToReal f = Inexact $ \n -> case f n of
    Exact x -> approximateQ x n
    Inexact g -> g n

instance Floating Computable where
    pi = inexactToReal $ \n -> go n 1 (sqrt 0.5) 0.25 1 where
        go n a b t x = if a - b < 10 ^^ negate n
            then (a + b)^2 / (4 * t)
            else let
                newA = (a + b) / 2
                newB = sqrt (b * a)
                in go n newA newB (t - x * (newA - a)^2) (2 * x)
```

$\text{approximateQ}(q,n) = \lfloor q × 10^n \rceil$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. `inexactToReal` flattens nested `Inexact`s.

But there is a problem. The implementation I refered to is in [this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3412.pdf) but it looks like the paper assumes the comparison to end iterations (`a - b < 10 ^^ negate n`) will be done in $O(1)$ time. But my implementation won't:

```
inexactify :: Computable -> Computable
inexactify (Exact x) = Inexact (approximateQ x)
inexactify x = x

instance Ord Computable where
    compare (Exact x) (Exact y) = compare x y
    compare (Inexact f) (Inexact g) = go 0 where
        go n = compare (f n) (g n) <> go (n + 1)
    compare x y = compare (inexactify x) (inexactify y)
```

`inexactify` removes the guarantee that the number is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $n$ be the location below the decimal point where the numbers start to differ. Since it takes $O(m)$ time to compare $m$-digit integers, assuming it takes $O(1)$ to evaluate both operands, it will take $O(n^2)$ time to compare numbers in $\mathbb{M}$. If the numbers are equal, the method won't halt. This is inevitable, for it is proven that there doesn't exist an algorithm that compares numbers in $\mathbb{M}$.

Furthermore, it actually doesn't take $O(1)$ to evaluate both operands. Gauss-Legendre algorithm recursively stacks `sqrt`s. Given that there is $m$ `sqrt`s stacked and I want to evaluate it, it takes $\Omega(2^m)$ time. If I were to evaluate $\pi$ to $n$ precisions, though I didn't do exact analysis, I persume it will take $\Omega(n!)$ time.

**TL;DR:** So I have a different plan. Given that I have to evaluate $\pi$ to $n$ precisions, rather than doing comparison to decide whether to end iterations, I will estimate the required number of iterations at the first place. But how? Since Gauss-Legendre algorithm has quadratic convergence, in theory, the number of precision must be doubled each iteration, but it actually seems to converge faster:
$$
3.14\cdots \quad \text{(precision 2)}
$$
$$
3.1415926\cdots \quad \text{(precision 7)}
$$
$$
3.141592653589793238\cdots \quad \text{(precision 18)}
$$

How can I estimate the numbers of precision given that there has been $m$ iterations? Not asymptotically, I need a formula in closed form.

Comment: "Iterations" is surely not the right thing to say, since Gauss-Legendre just involves adding up $n$ terms of the form $w_n f(x_n)$, where $w$ and $x$ are the weights and the abscissas of the $n$-point Gauss-Legendre rule. Also, there are far more efficient methods for computing $\pi$, like the AGM; see e.g. [Borwein's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=YV4PAQAAMAAJ).

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician I thought Gauss-Legendre IS the AGM? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm

Comment: Ah, this is why the terminology is sometimes confusing. I was under the mistaken impression you were doing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature). Since you are doing AGM, you could exploit the property of quadratic convergence; that is, the number of correct digits doubles with each step. So for safety, get the power of two larger than the number of your required digits, and then take the binary logarithm of that.